# Update existing react native android app to pure native android native

Tags: android, mobile, react-native

If i have react native android app in the playstore,
   i want to update that app with
  pure android native(java/kotlin) means is that possible.

Comment: yes, just build the app with the same package ID and sign it with the same signature

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. You'll just have to write app from scratch with same package and sign it with s same keystore. Then upload to market.

Comment: Thank u Konstantin Berkow